# Error main.lua:80: attempt to perform arithmetic on field 'y' (a nil value) -- LOVE2D

Tags: lua, love2d

I'm more new at coding and like a challenge so I'm using Lua and LOVE. But, this damn Error
main.lua:80: attempt to perform arithmetic on field 'y' (a nil value) keeps appearing when I run the game. Anyway to fix this, I'm sure it's simple, I'm pretty dumb.

```
-- Load Love2D module
local love = require('love')

-- Define global variables
local player = {}
local ground = {}
local camera = {}
local enemy = {}

-- Load game assets
function love.load()
  -- Load player asset
  player.img = love.graphics.newImage('player.png')
  player.x = 50
  player.y = 250
  player.speed = 150
  player.jump_height = -300
  player.gravity = 500
  player.velocity = 0
  player.width = player.img:getWidth()
  player.height = player.img:getHeight()
  player.health = 5
  player.dead = false

  -- Load ground asset
  ground.img = love.graphics.newImage('ground.png')
  ground.width = ground.img:getWidth()
  ground.height = ground.img:getHeight()
  ground.length = 50

  -- Load enemy asset
  enemy.img = love.graphics.newImage('enemy.png')
  enemy.width = enemy.img:getWidth()
  enemy.height = enemy.img:getHeight()
  enemy.x = 500
  enemy.y = love.graphics.getHeight() - ground.height - enemy.height
  enemy.speed = 100
  enemy.health = 5
  enemy.dead = false
  enemy.attacking = false
  enemy.direction = 'left'
end

-- Handle user input
function love.keypressed(key)
  if key == 'space' and player.velocity == 0 then
    player.velocity = player.jump_height
  end
end

-- Handle mouse input
function love.mousepressed(x, y, button, istouch)
  if button == 1 and not enemy.dead and not player.dead then
    local mouse_x, mouse_y = love.graphics.inverseTransformPoint(x, y)
    if mouse_x >= enemy.x and mouse_x <= enemy.x + enemy.width and
       mouse_y >= enemy.y and mouse_y <= enemy.y + enemy.height then
      enemy.health = enemy.health - 1
      if enemy.health == 0 then
        enemy.dead = true
      end
    end
  end
end

-- Update game state
function love.update(dt)
  -- Move player left and right
  if not player.dead then
    if love.keyboard.isDown('a') then
      player.x = player.x - player.speed * dt
    elseif love.keyboard.isDown('d') then
      player.x = player.x + player.speed * dt
    end

    -- Apply gravity to player
    player.velocity = player.velocity + player.gravity * dt
    player.y = player.y + player.velocity * dt

    -- Check if player is on the ground
    if player.y + player.height > love.graphics.getHeight() - ground.height - camera.y then
      player.velocity = 0
      player.y = love.graphics.getHeight() - ground.height - player.height - camera.y
    end

    -- Check if player is touching enemy
    if not enemy.dead and player.x + player.width > enemy.x and player.x < enemy.x + enemy.width and
       player.y + player.height > enemy.y and player.y < enemy.y + enemy.height then
      player.health = player.health - 1
      if player.health == 0 then
        player.dead = true
        player.health = 5
        player.x = 50
        player.y = 250
      end
    end
  end

  -- Update enemy position
  if not enemy.attacking then
    if enemy.direction == 'left' then
      enemy.x = enemy.x - enemy.speed * dt
      if enemy.x < 0 then
        enemy.direction = 'right'
      end
    elseif enemy.direction == 'right' then
      enemy.x = enemy.x + enemy.speed * dt
      if enemy.x + enemy.width > love.graphics.getWidth() then
        enemy.direction = 'left'
      end
    end
  
    -- Check if enemy sees player
    if player.x + player.width > enemy.x and player.x < enemy.x + enemy.width and
       player.y + player.height > enemy.y and player.y < enemy.y + enemy.height then
      enemy.attacking = true
    end
  else
    -- Move enemy towards player
    if enemy.x > player.x then
      enemy.x = enemy.x - enemy.speed * dt
      enemy.direction = 'left'
    elseif enemy.x < player.x then
      enemy.x = enemy.x + enemy.speed * dt
      enemy.direction = 'right'
    end
  
    -- Attack player if within range
    if player.x + player.width > enemy.x and player.x < enemy.x + enemy.width and
       player.y + player.height > enemy.y and player.y < enemy.y + enemy.height then
      player.health = player.health - 1
      if player.health == 0 then
        player.dead = true
        player.health = 5
        player.x = 50
        player.y = 250
      end
    else
      -- Stop attacking if player is out of range
      enemy.attacking = false
    end
  end
  
-- Initialize camera table
local camera = {
    x = 0,
    y = 0
  }
  
  -- Update camera position
  camera.y = player.y - love.graphics.getHeight() / 2 + player.height / 2
  if camera.y < 0 then
    camera.y = 0
  elseif camera.y > ground.height * ground.length - love.graphics.getHeight() then
    camera.y = ground.height * ground.length - love.graphics.getHeight()
  end
end  
  
  -- Draw game objects
  function love.draw()
    -- Draw ground
    for i = 0, ground.length - 1 do
      love.graphics.draw(ground.img, i * ground.width, love.graphics.getHeight() - ground.height - camera.y)
    end
  
    -- Draw player
    if not player.dead then
      love.graphics.draw(player.img, player.x, player.y - camera.y)
    end
  
    -- Draw enemy
    if not enemy.dead then
      love.graphics.draw(enemy.img, enemy.x, enemy.y - camera.y)
    end
  
    -- Draw player health
    if not player.dead then
      love.graphics.print('Health: ' .. player.health, 10, 10)
    end
  
    -- Draw enemy health
    if not enemy.dead then
      love.graphics.print('Enemy Health: ' .. enemy.health, love.graphics.getWidth() - 150, 10)
    end
  end
```

I tried to look for any "Y's" in the code that could be messed up but I just can't find anything.

Comment: In the end of `love.update`, you create local table camera with initial values - so you wouldn't affect global `camera` table in updates. Move this initialization to the top of file.

Answer (score 0):

Lua Error Message is right...

```
-- Define local variables
local player = {}
local ground = {}
local camera = {y = 0} -- Tadah!!!
local enemy = {}
```